# How to use Android DataBinding with Groovy (grooid)

Tags: android, groovy, android-databinding, grooid

I'm using joint compilation (having .java files in the groovy src directory) so that java and groovy can reference each other.
However, when using google's data-binding lib, the compiler fails to find the classes referenced in the layout.xml file.
I always get a 'Cannot resolve type for user'
Is there a workaround this ?

Answer (score 0):

Databinding requires annotation processing that Google hides in Android Studio. See this example of how to get it setup for a groovy application https://github.com/pieces029/groovy-android-data-binding